# How to understand function ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const unsigned char* s)

Tags: c++

For function declaration like

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const unsigned char* s);
```

I am wondering what has been returned. The CPP reference says it returns ostream object. But why it is ostream& instead of simple ostream?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

The reason that the operator returns a `ostream&` (i.e. a modifiable reference to an `ostream` object), rather than a copy or void is that it allows for chaining, for instance, a common example with `std::cout` as the `ostream` object:

```
unsigned int i = 2;
std::cout << "This is a test to print " << "some text and maybe some numbers: " << i << std::endl;
```

Here we chain two `const char*`s, an `unsigned int` and a stream modifer, without having to seperate them with separate lines, this makes it nicer to read and understand.

Answer (score 4):

First reason: `std::ostream`s are not copyable in general (in C++11 the copy constructor is actually `delete`d).  You don't want to return a copy anyway because chaining wouldn't work:

```
    std::stringstream s;
    s << "String1" << "String2";
```

would fail to compile because because the copy returned by the first operator call would not be convertible to the reference required for the second call.
Making both values instead of references also wouldn't work:

```
    std::stringstream s;
    s << "String1" << "String2";
    assert(s.str() == "String1String2");
```

Your code will compile but the assert will fail because the object `s` remains unmodified after these calls because it was passed by copy instead of by reference.

Second reason: all the actual `stream` objects you will use derive from `std::ostream`.  If this parameter were passed by copy then you get [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/1277769) where you effectively lose the object you were using.
This means the following code wouldn't work (if passing by reference but returning by copy- and somehow getting around the compilation error?):

```
    std::stringstream s;
    s << "String1" << "String2" << std::endl;
    assert(s == "String1String2");
```

`s` would only hold `"String1"` in this case because when you returned the `std::stringstream` by copy of `std::ostream`, the returned object is no longer a `std::stringstream` object and calling `operator<<` on that passes `"String2"` into a temporary object which just gets destroyed by the end.

Those are the two important reasons I can think of to return by reference and not by value.

Answer (score 1):

Because you return "os" like that you can do a chaining;

```
std::cout << "string1" << "string2" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Returning simple objects would require the compiler to generate an object copy but returning references don't.